# Web Scraping with BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have some html data given below i want to extract the all times from the webpage and then store the all data inside a list Variable. How can i do that.. Help Please..

```
<div class=panchang-box-secondary-header>
<div class="list-wrapper pl-2">
<div class="list-style-thumbnail list-layout-horizontal">
<div class="list-item-outer py-2">
<div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center">
<span class="icon-sprite icon-sprite-sunrise"></span>
<div class=flex-grow-1>
<span class="d-block t-sm">सूर्योदय</span>
<span class="d-block b">5:31 AM</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="list-item-outer py-2">
<div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center">
<span class="icon-sprite icon-sprite-sunset"></span>
<div class=flex-grow-1>
<span class="d-block t-sm">सूर्यास्त</span>
<span class="d-block b">7:24 PM</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="list-item-outer py-2">
<div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center">
<span class="icon-sprite icon-sprite-moonrise"></span>
<div class=flex-grow-1>
<span class="d-block t-sm">चन्द्रोदय</span>
<span class="d-block b">10:05 PM</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="list-item-outer py-2">
<div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center">
<span class="icon-sprite icon-sprite-moonset"></span>
<div class=flex-grow-1>
<span class="d-block t-sm">चन्द्रास्त</span>
<span class="d-block b">9:12 AM</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
a = '''<div class=panchang-box-secondary-header>
<div class="list-wrapper pl-2">
<div class="list-style-thumbnail list-layout-horizontal">
<div class="list-item-outer py-2">
<div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center">
<span class="icon-sprite icon-sprite-sunrise"></span>
<div class=flex-grow-1>
<span class="d-block t-sm">सूर्योदय</span>
<span class="d-block b">5:31 AM</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="list-item-outer py-2">
<div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center">
<span class="icon-sprite icon-sprite-sunset"></span>
<div class=flex-grow-1>
<span class="d-block t-sm">सूर्यास्त</span>
<span class="d-block b">7:24 PM</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="list-item-outer py-2">
<div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center">
<span class="icon-sprite icon-sprite-moonrise"></span>
<div class=flex-grow-1>
<span class="d-block t-sm">चन्द्रोदय</span>
<span class="d-block b">10:05 PM</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="list-item-outer py-2">
<div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center">
<span class="icon-sprite icon-sprite-moonset"></span>
<div class=flex-grow-1>
<span class="d-block t-sm">चन्द्रास्त</span>
<span class="d-block b">9:12 AM</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(a,'html.parser')
time = soup.select('.d-block.b')
times = [times.text for times in time]
print(times)
```

Output:

```
['5:31 AM', '7:24 PM', '10:05 PM', '9:12 AM']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just extract "d-block b" and push it into wherever you want.

Comment: Can you please reply me with full code please... I am newbie in Web scraping...

Answer (score 1):

```
time = soup.find_all(class_ = "d-block b").text
```

This will make a list that gets all the time in the webpage source and store it in the variable **time**